# coldfusion url variable issue

Tags: coldfusion

Sometimes we are passing url strings such as follows:

```
http://www.oursite.com/index.cfm?layout=displayNews&amp;newsArticle=1837
```

Notice the `"&amp;"` in the url. This causes issues on the receiving page, which sees the url variable as `url.AMP;newsArticle` We cannot always control whether it arrives this way or as "&".

In the receiving page, we would like to deal with the possibility that either format may arrive. I've made a few weak attempts that don't work, e.g.

```
<cfif structkeyexists(url,'AMP;NEWSARTICLE')>
     <cfset url.newsArticle = evaluate('#url.AMP;NEWSARTICLE#')> <!--- this line errors on the semicolon after AMP --->
</cfif>
```

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing strings in cgi.query_string won't fix the problem, as the URL scope is populated at that point.

You can reference the value as a struct:

```
<cfset url.newsarticle = url['amp;newsarticle']>
```

So combine that with structKeyExists:

```
<cfif structkeyexists(url,'AMP;NEWSARTICLE')>
    <cfset url.newsarticle = url['amp;newsarticle]>
</cfif>
```

Extending this further, you can filter out the entire URL scope:

```
<cfloop collection="#url#" item="key">
    <cfif left(key,4) eq "amp;">
        <cfset url[replace(key,"amp;","")] = url[key]>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Should it be url['amp;newsarticle']? You seem to have missed a single quote before the closing square bracket.

Comment: Thanks, fixed - trying to type with a bandaid on my hand :)

Comment: And if it always follows the same pattern you could even integrate that into your Application.cfc

Comment: I get the error Element amp;newsarticle is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.filter.UrlScope.

Comment: hang on, I might have boobooed

Comment: Confirm what's in the URL scope by doing <cfdump var="#url#">

Comment: "Replacing the strings" true enough, you would have to reset the url variables after sanitizing the query string, My fault for not offering the complete answer. [I will update it]

Answer (score 0):

You might try a

```
 replaceNoCase(cgi.query_string, '&amp;', '&', 'all')
```

Then just process it normally.. that way only the html entities get replaced...

-sean

Answer (score 0):

There may be a cleaner way... but this seems to work for me (syntax assumes CF9):

```
<cfscript>
    cleanURL = {};

    for ( var item in URL ) {
        if ( left( item, 4 ) == "amp;" ) {
            key = replaceNoCase( item, 'amp;', '' ); // right() also works here
        } else {
            key = item;
        }

        cleanURL[ key ] = URL[ item ];
    }
</cfscript>

<cfdump var="#cleanURL#" />
```

Comment: I see we have pretty much the same thoughts, but I prefer to "patch" the original scope, to minimize changes to rest of code. As mz_01 pointed out, this could be placed in Application.cfc and the code wouldn't know that the URL scope was messed up :-)

Comment: They're both right, but if the URL scope isn't parsed correctly you might end up with garbage in the URL parameter names. Depending on the situation you might want to combine it with Sean's recommendation below.